# How to change the layout of multicolumn index?

Tags: indexing

The default multicolumn index looks like this:

```
AA       d
  a    BB
  b      a
  c      b
```

How could I change it into:

```
AA
  a      c
  b      d
BB
  a      b
```

which breaks the multicolumn at every group?

Comment: Perhaps »[idxlayout](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout)« can help here.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I have tried `imakeidx` and `idxlayout`, but didn't find out any solutions.

Comment: So you can for sure [show what you have tried](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so far and supplement your question correspondingly.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I have tried to write `group_skip = "\\end{multicol}\\begin{multicol}"` to the `.ist` file, which gets the best so far; but some styles are abnormal after the first group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote that you modified your .ist file, so I suppose you use makeindex. I wrote a solution that needs xindy.

You did not tell us how you create the groups, I supposed you write

> \index{AA!a}

The very inelegant trick that I used was to re-define the \item command inside the index environment.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
\begin{filecontents*}{saltystyle.xdy}
(markup-locclass-list :open "\nopage{" :sep "" :close "}" )
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}\onecolumn~n
\makeatletter
\def\item#1 {\par\hangindent 40\p@ #1\par\begin{multicols}{2}}
\makeatother

 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{}"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \item "           :close "~n\end{multicols}" :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n   \subitem "     :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=xindy, options= -M saltystyle.xdy]
\newcommand{\nopage}[1]{}
\begin{document}
Hallo!
\index{AA!a}\index{AA!b}\index{AA!c}\index{AA!d}
\index{BB!a}\index{BB!b}\index{BB!c}\index{BB!d}

\printindex
\end{document}
```